# Tagging Jmeter Test Cases

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am looking for a way to tag Jmeter test cases.
We are using Jmeter for functional test , so we have a lot of test cases , not every test cases are run for every application configuration.
So based on configuration we need tag our test cases and run the test set accordingly from command line.
(Some thing we can do in testng and other framework , where you tag TC and during run you provide the tag so that TC only with that tag are executed)

If there is no tagging available then i feel that i will need to create multiple test set as per configuration and run them accordingly.
In most cases the Test overlap between this test sets and this will result in duplication and require quite a good maintenance.

Please suggest if you all see any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I can think of is explained below:
 - Declare a property for every test cases
 - Process that property to execute your test cases. Use If Controller to check whether that property is passed or not
 - Control that property via command line or via GUI. If you want to run some of them pass that property only.

Practical example is shown below:

1. Test Plan will look like this:

   - Test Case steps will be inside If controller, and if controller will decide whether to run that Test Case or not, depending upon what you are passing in that property.

[image]

2. Property declaration for all you test cases.

   - I have designed this in such a way that you can execute that via GUI as well as via command prompt.

[image]

3. If Controller logic

   - `${__BeanShell("${TC1}"=="ON",)}`

[image]

4. Execution via command line

   - `jmeter -n -t <>.jmx -JTC1=ON -JTC3=ON -j sample.log`
   - Here I am running TC1 and TC3, depending upon your requirement you can pass whichever scenario you need to execute.

Comment: This looks as a fine approach considering that i was not able to locate any other approach on how to handle this. Thank you SAIR